# How to display text links center and side by side with css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, vertical-alignment

I have three pieces of text, `Events` `Find an Event` and `Post an event`

`Events` is positioned correctly in the centre of the page, but `Post An Event` and `Find An Event` are positioned left of centre.

How do I put these two pieces of text next to each other (same line) and in the centre of the page?

Tried.

```
.postanevent {text-align : center! important; display: 
inline-block! Important;}
.findanevent] text-align: center! Important; display: inline- 
block! Important; }
```

Here is my html:

```
<div class="entry-content">
<div class="lasvegas">
Events
</div>
<div class="findanevent"><a 
href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/"></p>
<div class="findanevent"><font size="3"><font 
color="white">Find an Event</font></font></div>
<p></a></p>
<div class="postanevent"><a 
href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/"></p>
<div class="postanevent"><font size="3"><font 
color="white">Post an Event</font></font></div>
<p></a></p>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->
<footer class="entry-footer">
<span class="edit-link"><a class="post-edit-link" 
href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-admin/post.php? 
post=6811&#038;action=edit">Edit <span class="screen- 
reader-text">"Events"</span></a></span> </footer><!-- 
.entry-footer -->
</article><!-- #post-## -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

Page: https://adsler.co.uk/events/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a wrapper around the two anchors to center them both in the same line:

```css
.event_wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="event_wrapper">
  <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/"><span id="findanevent" class="event">Find an Event</span></a>
  <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/"><span id="postanevent" class="event">Post an Event</span></a>
</div>
```

don't use the font tag anymore, it is deprecated. You can just use the classes you already have or add a new one like I did.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. So what would the whole thing look like, bearing in mind i want font color white and font size 3?e.g, how to incorporate what you wrote into my existing html as listed in the question?

Comment: add to the CSS: 
.event { font-size:1em; color:#fff; }

the font-size:3 does only work with the <font> tag which is deprecated.

Comment: So how would i incorporate into this html:? `<div class="lasvegas">
Events</div>
<div class="findanevent">

&nbsp;
<div class="findanevent"><span style="font-size: medium;"><span style="color: white;">Find an Event</span></span></div>
&nbsp;
<div class="postanevent">

&nbsp;
<div class="postanevent"><span style="font-size: medium;"><span style="color: white;">Post an Event</span></span></div>
&nbsp;

</div>
</div>`

Comment: Also: What are you using to edit the code? You have a lot of unnecessary "&nbsp;" and other stuff (empty <p> tags) in the code.

Comment: Would you mind just putting what you said into the following html please, deleting adding as necessary? `<div class="lasvegas">
Events</div>
<div class="findanevent">

&nbsp;
<div class="findanevent"><span style="font-size: medium;"><span style="color: white;">Find an Event</span></span></div>
&nbsp;
<div class="postanevent">

&nbsp;
<div class="postanevent"><span style="font-size: medium;"><span style="color: white;">Post an Event</span></span></div>
&nbsp;

</div>
</div>`

Comment: It works, the text is just black. Add this to your CSS: ".event { color: #fff; }"

Comment: Ok.and then how do i separate the two links? They are very close together??

Comment: There are many ways, but you can just add a padding: .event {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
}

Comment: `<div class="lasvegas">
Events</div>
<div class="findanevent"> </div>

<div class="event_wrapper"><a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/"><span id="findanevent" class="event">Find an Event</span></a>
<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/"><span id="postanevent" class="event">Post an Event</span></a></div>`

Comment: `.events {color:#fff; padding: 20px;}`

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your links inside a div the use display flex. there are many ways to do this but I prefer flex it easy.

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <div class="links-wrapper">
        <div class="lasvegas">
            Events
        </div>
        <div class="findanevent">
            <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/">Find an Event</a>
        </div>
        <div class="postanevent">
            <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/">Post an Event</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- .entry-content -->


<style type="text/css">
    .entry-content{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .links-wrapper{
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
                justify-content: center;
    }
    .links-wrapper > div{
        margin: 0 15px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Also, its important that you wrap your html properly!

Comment: Ok. Did what you said and here's how the page looks now https://adsler.co.uk/events/

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `findanevent` and `postanevent` divs into a main wrapper like `<div class="eventsWrap">` and put this in a `display:flex` property. So that the two divs will be in same line. Because by default the `display:flex` property shows the child element into same line like inline or rows. Next you have to add a property is `justify-content:center;, align-items:center;, align-content:center; align-self:center;`. Hope it may help you! Good luck.

```
.eventsWrap { display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; align-content:center; align-self:center;}
```

Comment: How would i incorporate into this html?`<div class="lasvegas">
Events</div>
<div class="findanevent">

&nbsp;
<div class="findanevent"><span style="font-size: medium;"><span style="color: white;">Find an Event</span></span></div>
&nbsp;
<div class="postanevent">

&nbsp;
<div class="postanevent"><span style="font-size: medium;"><span style="color: white;">Post an Event</span></span></div>
&nbsp;

</div>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

you can take these 3 in flex box:

```
<div style=" display: flex;justify-content: center;">
 <div Events></div>
 <div Find an Event></div> 
 <div Post an event></div>
</div>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: How would i incorporate into this html `<div class="lasvegas">
Events</div>
<div class="findanevent">

&nbsp;
<div class="findanevent"><span style="font-size: medium;"><span style="color: white;">Find an Event</span></span></div>
&nbsp;
<div class="postanevent">

&nbsp;
<div class="postanevent"><span style="font-size: medium;"><span style="color: white;">Post an Event</span></span></div>
&nbsp;

</div>
</div>`

Comment: @Sta your code seems wrong. It contains `<p></a></p>` kind of typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for set links

```
<div class="entry-content" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="lasvegas">
       Events
    </div>
    <div class="findanevent">
        <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/find-an-event/">
            <div class="findanevent">
                <font size="3">
                    <font color="black">Find an Event</font>
                </font>
          </div>
        </a>
        <div class="postanevent">
            <a href="https://adsler.co.uk/post-an-event/">
                <div class="postanevent">
                    <font size="3">
                        <font color="black">Post an Event</font>
                    </font>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
       <!-- .entry-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- #primary -->
</div>

<style>
    .lasvegas{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .findanevent{
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

I hope this one is helpful